# ssh - ForceCommand executing in sftp session

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sftp

I added the following line to my sshd_config:

```
...
ForceCommand /bin/ssh-alert
...
```

the `ssh-alert` file looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
SSH_IP=$(echo $SSH_CLIENT | head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}')
yowsup-cli demos -c $YOWSUP_CONF -s $PHONENUMBER "SSH Alert! Login from IP $SSH_IP" > /dev/null 2>&1

#the important part:
/bin/bash --login
```

Now the problem is that if I start a SSH session in the program MobaXTerm the SFTP window is empty and after closing the ssh session it says: `Waiting for the pending transfer to complete...`.

If I change `/bin/bash --login` in the `ssh-alert` file to `/bin/bash` (without --login) It works again, but my .bashrc, .bash_profile, /etc/bash.bashrc won't get sourced.

Is there a way to only execute ForceCommand if it is a SSH session and not a SFTP session. Or a way to check if it is a SFTP session in my bash script.

NOTE: My .bash_profile has a command with output. If I would disable that output it would work again.

EDIT: FileZilla SFTP does not work, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to only execute ForceCommand if it is a SSH session and not a SFTP session.

No.

> Or a way to check if it is a SFTP session in my bash script.

This is what `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` is for. You should be able to differentiate using that if the command is SFTP or not

> NOTE: My `.bash_profile` has a command with output. If I would disable that output it would work again.

That is the problem which is breaking SFTP protocol. You should not generate any output if the shell is not interactive:

```
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  # generate output
fi
```

Comment: `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` is always empty in my case. I changed my bash_profile so the command only executes `if [ "$PS1" ];`. Now I don't even get a SFTP connection.

Comment: You can use the `$PS1` in your script too to detect if it is interactive or not.

Comment: I put that if clause to my ssh-alert file, but it does not change anything. If I do `if [ "$PS1" ]; then /bin/bash else /bin/bash --login fi` I have the same problem. And if i swap it --login wont be executed.

Comment: Can you try something like this: `[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'Not interactive'` (from [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch)).

Comment: So after some testing I came to the conslusion, that the problem is not the output. It is the ForceCommand itself. If I just do /bin/bash it does not work either. I just decided to not use ForceCommand and just put the ssh-alert command to my `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

If `ForceCommand` is run by `sshd`, then the daemon drops any further action with this session. It will never check if it's sftp and if it needs an "sftp subsystem". SFTP session cannot talk to `bash`, this is what `ssh` and `scp` are for.

For SFTP to work, the `ForceCommand` script should in the end exec the `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` or some similar handler.